# Disparar um evento ao pressionar o botão volume 2x?

Tags: java, android, eventos

Gostaria de disparar um evento somente ao ser pressionado o botão volume 2x rapidamente.

Tenho o seguinte código, mas ele dispara ao pressionar o botão uma única vez. Como fazer com que seja disparado somente se pressionado 2 vezes num certa velocidade?

Segue o código:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                toDoUp();
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                toDoDown();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é possível fazer mas o primeiro click será passado ao sistema. Serve assim?

Comment: Ou seja o indicador de volume irá abrir. Se servir assim eu dou uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo funcional abaixo, modifique-o de forma que atenda suas necessidades :

KeyPressTool :

```
public class KeyPressTool {

private static int doublePressSpeed = 300; // double keypressed in ms
private static long timeKeyDown = 0;       // last keyperessed time
public static int lastKeyPressedCode;

public static  boolean isDoublePress(KeyEvent ke) {
    if ((ke.getWhen() - timeKeyDown) < doublePressSpeed) {
        return true;
    } else {
        timeKeyDown = ke.getWhen();
    }
    lastKeyPressedCode = ke.getKeyCode();
    return false;
}
}
```

---

// Testando

```
f (KeyPressTool.isDoublePress(ke) && KeyPressTool.lastKeyPressedCode == ke.getKeyCode()) {
System.out.println("double pressed " + ke.getKeyText(ke.getKeyCode());
}
```

Comment: Que método é esse `getWhen()`?

Comment: Retorna o timestamp de quando esse evento ocorreu.

Comment: Não o encontro na classe KeyEvent.

Comment: Este método getWhen() foi criado por você, correto?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getWhen()

Comment: Sei que não é legal postar link, só que assim vocês vão entender melhor...

Comment: Também não o achei na classe KeyEvent

Comment: Nestas situações não tem mal passar links. A classe KeyEvent do Android é diferente e não tem esse método.

Comment: Posso ter me enganado, como estou no trabalho não tive como testar, assim que chegar irei dar uma olhada.